# Crystal Reports XI Record Selection Issue using Multiple Criteria

Tags: crystal-reports

A huge thanks to anyone that tries to help me in advance!

I'm not a programmer, but I have to work with Crystal Reports XI at work.

I have been asked to put together a report that will allow us to see all of the cases numbers that have the following criteria:  It must have a `0` in the `AE field` for the previous three months.

So `Jan 2015 AE=0, Dec 2014 AE=0 and Nov 2014 AE=0.` In other words if a case has `0 AE` for those three months it will show up.  If not it won't.

I've worked on this for several days and stumped (like I said I'm not a programmer and have learned a high appreciation for the talents and skills programmers bring to the table!

What I have so far is only one of numerous attempts to get the results I'm looking for, but here is the formula I currently have in the Record Select

(which of course does not work):

```
{CASE.CASE_OWNER} = "TIM" and
not ({UNIT.RESP_CODE} in "20" to "74") and
{CASE.ARCHIVE} = "F" and
{MICRO_DATA.AE} = 0.00 and {MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2015" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "01" and 
{MICRO_DATA.AE} = 0.00 and {MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2014" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "12" and 
{MICRO_DATA.AE} = 0.00 and {MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2014" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "11"
```

Answer (score 1):

your `and` conditions are creating problems.

```
    {CASE.CASE_OWNER} = "TIM" and
    not ({UNIT.RESP_CODE} in "20" to "74") and
    {CASE.ARCHIVE} = "F" and
    {MICRO_DATA.AE} = 0.00 and 
    ({MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2015" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "01") OR 
    ({MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2014" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "12") OR 
    ({MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2014" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "11")
```

This is one way and one more way is to don't write in record selection formula just write in you condition in formulas and pick data.

Edit..........................

```
and not(databasefield  in "")
```

Edit---------------------

```
if ({MICRO_DATA.REF_YY} = "2015" and {MICRO_DATA.REF_MM} = "01" and isNull(yourdatabasefield))
then true
else false
```

write this in supress part of the date field where you are displaying

Comment: Your answer is much appreicated!  The problem I'm still having is that I need all 7 conditions to be met while also not showing null fields.  The above suggestion gives me data, but now it's showing every case that has a null value for January 2015.  How to do get rid of the cases with a null value?

Comment: for which field you don't need null value?

Comment: Basically if the January 2015 field has no data in it I don't want that case to show up on the report.  Technically I think that is two fields.  Am I communicating well?  I hope so.  I really do appreaciate the help.

Comment: you need to use supress option to hide the field that shows null... but your month and year field are different I am not sure how are you manuplating... check my edit for supress

Comment: Didn't work.  I think the problem lies in that I need multiple conditions to be met and I don't know how to code them; i.e. AE=null and Year=2015 is also null and Month=01 is also null.  So if the AE=null for January 2015 then I want that record to be suppressed.

Comment: You can include all conditions using OR in between if you can paste your formula will try to help